# python os.sytem kill process from cgi

Tags: python, linux, process

I am trying to kill a process from a webpage.

```
import os

os.system(“killall Laser”)

print("Content-Type: text/HTML;charset=utf-8")
print("")
print("Laser has been restarted.")
```

The file permission is set to 777 and I have set the setuid and setgid.  The script works when I run it from the command line but not in the browser.

This is running on ubuntu and the webserver is lighthttp.

The process is owned by root.

I have also tried using:

```
import subprocess as sub, cgitb

cgitb.enable(display=0, logdir="/tmp")

p = sub.Popen(['killall;', 'Laser'],shell=True,stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE)
output, errors = p.communicate()
print("Content-Type: text/HTML;charset=utf-8")
print("")
print(output)
```

and:

```
import subprocess as sub, cgitb

cgitb.enable(display=0, logdir="/tmp")

cmd1 = "su root"
cmd2 = "killall Laser"
p = sub.Popen("{}; {}".format(cmd1, cmd2),shell=True,stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE, close_fds=True)
output, errors = p.communicate()
print("Content-Type: text/HTML;charset=utf-8")
print("")
print(output)
```

Any ideas?

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You should assign .py files to be ran as CGI/fastcgi-scripts through ligghtpd in it's config:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/cgi-bin/" {
        cgi.assign = ( ".py" => "/usr/bin/python" )
}
```

And don't forget about shebang (#!/usr/bin/env python) on the first line of python script.
Read here for more details: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1166401

Comment: The python script is working okay.  The process is started by root so I don't think the webpage has permissions to delete it.  Is there a way in python to pass in something like this: su -s root before trying to kill the process?